# React hook useState's setter inside function doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to do a refactor of a countdown component that a project I'm working on has.

When I finished the migration of the logic the value of the counter didn't work. I decided to start from zero in codesandbox, so I tought of the simplest implementation and came out with this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(60);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {counter}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App timerSeconds={360} />, rootElement);
```

What it happens here is that the value of `counter` stays on 59 after the first run of the interval.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/flamboyant-moon-ogyqr

### Second iteration on issue

Thank you for the response Ross, but the real issue happens when I link the countdown to a handler:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(60);
  const [countdownInterval, setCountdownInterval] = useState(null);


  const startCountdown = () => {
    setCountdownInterval(setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearInterval(countdownInterval);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={startCountdown}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {counter}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App timerSeconds={360} />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `counter` variable within the second parameter (the array) of the `useEffect` function. When you pass in an empty array, it will only update the `state` once on the initial render. An empty array is often used when you're making an HTTP request or something along those lines instead. (Edited for second iteration)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(5);
  const [counterId, setCounterId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearInterval(counterId);
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {

    /* 
     * I'd take startCountdown and make
     * it's own component/hook out of it, 
     * so it can be easily reused and expanded.
     */
    const startCountdown = setInterval(() => {
      return setCounter((tick) => {
        if (tick === 0) {
          clearInterval(counterId);
          setCounter(0);
          return setCounterId(null);
        };

        return tick - 1;
      });
    }, 1000)

    setCounterId(startCountdown);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={handleClick}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {counter}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App timerSeconds={360} />, rootElement);
```

For more information on this implementation, read about React Hooks and skipping effects at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects.

Comment: I set this as the answer since this resolve my first issue but I'm still having issues with this. Just updated the comment and added a second iteration.

Comment: Just one thing @Ross Sheppard, `id` was never set, and the interval should be cleared on component's unmount. The countdown works, but for performance. I've tried to keep the timer ID on a state variable but countdown keeps working: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-beaver-puuus

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) version of the function returned by useState to compute the new state based on the previous state.

Your updated code would look like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(60);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {setCounter(counter => counter - 1);}, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {counter}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App timerSeconds={360} />, rootElement);
```

UPDATE EDIT
Here is a version that starts the countdown with a click handler:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(60);
  const [countdownInterval, setCountdownInterval] = useState(null);


  const startCountdown = () => {
    setCountdownInterval(setInterval(() => setCounter(counter => counter - 1), 1000));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearInterval(countdownInterval);
  }, [countdownInterval]);

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={startCountdown}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {counter}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App timerSeconds={360} />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This is also a valid solution, but when you link the `setInterval` into a handler, any of the options stops working.

Comment: This is not just another valid solution. This is the only correct solution.